# Zend Lucene query

Tags: php, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I'm adding these fields when I store data in Lucene:

```
$index->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('id', $entry->id));
$index->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('type', $entry->type));
```

How can make a query to retrieve only data with a certain type?

I tried:

```
 $query = "type IN ('a', 'b', 'c')"; // get data that has either of these types
 $this->query->addSubquery(Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($query), true);
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: ok, I found out a solution using `type:(a) OR type:(b)` etc..

Comment: Would you please consider to put your comment as an actual answer? It's [OK to self-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. And it would help to keep the "Unanswered" list clear for questions really still being unanswered^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well my solution was:

`$query = "type:(a) OR type:(b)";`

and it is also ok to write it like this (grouping of fields):

`$query = "type:(a OR b)";`